# How to use scripts in Arbre?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, arbre

In the docs it says that to put JavaScript into Arbre you must use `script { raw ... }`. At first I understood from this to write `script { raw [insert code here]}`. With the word raw as being part of it. That didn't work. So then I thought it might be that it was `script {[insert code here]}`, but that also didn't work. I am writing the code as a string because if I try to write it directly, Ruby says the code is not ruby code and accuses an error. But when I look into the HTML with Inspect, the JS code appears almost perfectly there, except that wherever I put quotation marks, instead it is written `&quot;`, and I don't know how to make it so it actually places quotations properly.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
script { "alert('here we are');".html_safe }
```

Another way:

```
show do

  render \
    :partial => 'shared/myjavascript', 
    :locals => { 
      :how_did_we_get_here => 'yeah, also locals!' 
    }

  columns do
    column do
      attributes_table do
      # ....
    end
  end
end
```

Then in `app/views/shared/_myjavascript.html.erb` place the following:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  alert("<%= how_did_we_get_here %>");
<% end %>
```